# NodeJS Send response after some task

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, websocket

I'm developing a node application which listens for http requests, pulls out the parameters and passes them on to another application via websocket, returning the applications reply as a http response.

Simplified code:

```
app -> express instance
ws -> websocket object
cbs -> array to store key, value (callback functions)


app.post('/someCall', function(req,res) {
    var msg = req.body;
    msg.cb_id = "cb_id|"+Date.now(); // create unique id for callback fn
    cbs[msg.cb_id] = function() { // save callback
        res.send('got reply from ws');
    }
    ws.send(msg); //forward to websocket
}


ws.on('message', function(message) { // fired when we get a response from 2nd application
    var msg = JSON.parse(message);
    if(typeof(cbs[msg.cb_id]) === 'function')) { // check if we have registered a callback
        cbs[msg.cb_id](); // execute the saved callback
        delete(cbs[msg.cb_id]); // remove
    }
});
```

To simplify things further for now, the 2nd application is a node instance which just echos any message it receives. I can confirm the message gets back, however I keep getting `Error: Request aborted`.

It seems as though the post handler falls through and the callback never gets called. I can verify that it does get called if I replace the function with say `console.log('it worked');` but can't get it to actually respond to the request.

So I guess the question is how can I keep the request open until I get a reply from the 2nd application, is this the right approach?

Comment: are u glued to websockets? or could u use something like socket.io?

Comment: using sockjs for the client, which is working fine

Comment: yah - just thinking - i know how to use socket.io and i have never had a problem where the socket was closing or whatever you say is happening to you - so i thought it might be an alternative if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, problem isn't the websocket though, its the http request getting aborted

Comment: where does the request happen? all i see is socket stuff

Comment: `app.post('/someCall', function(req,res)` is express http handler

Comment: ah - glanced over that

Comment: try putting `ws.send` inside `cbs[msg...` grouping

Comment: cbs[msg.cb_id] = function() { // save callback
        res.send('got reply from ws'); ws.send(msg); //forward to websocket
    }

Comment: any luck? did it work?

Comment: The callback will never be fired that way, the point is to register the function, send the message and call function when I get the reply.

Comment: oh i see - u are saving the function and calling it from `ws.on`

Comment: does `cbs[msg.cb_id] = function() { // save callback
        res.send('got reply from ws');
    }` have to be inside the post call? that is confusing me a bit.

Comment: sorry - i think i see what ur doing but im not sure if i can help without having something to mess with in front of me

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using middle-wears, as i did in following  code

```
app.post('/someCall',function(req,res,next){
    ws.send(req.body); 
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        req.params.resMessage = JSON.parse(message);
        next(); 
    });
},
function(req,res,next) {
    res.send('Got reply form ws : ' + req.params.resMessage);
}
);
```

If it didn't work, comment.
GL